# From where can i download RPM binary for my RedHat Enterprise Linux Server 7?

Tags: redhat, rpm

I have accidently deleted rpm binary by issuing incorrect command(rpm -e) on My RedHat Enterprise Linux Server 7. From where can i download the required binaries and copy it to the required place /usr/bin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packages for Red Hat Enterprise Linux can be downloaded only using yum and certificate which you get from `subscription-manager`. It is hard to do that manually.

What you can do easily is to get the package from CentOS (binary compatible distribution):

http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/

download it on some other system where you have rpm binary and do:

```
rpm2cpio downloaded-rpm.rpm | cpio -idmv
```

take the extracted files and copy it to the broken machine.

And then you should do

```
yum reinstall rpm
```

which will download the package again from Red Hat CDN and reinstall it even if it would be the same version.

Part of Red Hat Enterprise Linux added value is the support center. I highly recommend contacting Red Hat directly https://access.redhat.com/support next time.

Comment: after issuing the 1st command i am getting the following Error: error: Unable to open /usr/lib/rpm/rpmrc for reading : No such file or directory.

Comment: I edited my answer. You will need another machine with functional rpm to finish this.

Answer (score 0):

use this link to download the necessary binaries : http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/